# How to cast while creating a new object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

How could I do

```
employees.map(x=> {
 let obj: Human = {name: x.firstName};
 return obj;
});
```

but in a single ligne without declaring a variable obj?
So I would have VSCode intellisense while making my new object.

If I do

```
employees.map(x=> {name: x.FirstName});
```

I can't know availaible properties while typing.

My question may be badly worded and I am sorry in advance.

Comment: `employees.map(x => ({ name: x.FirstName } as Human));`

Comment: @AlekseyL. please post your answer so I can select it. It worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
employees.map(x => ({ name: x.FirstName } as Human));
```

Answer (score 2):

Map is a generic and you can specify return type:

```
employees.map<Human>(x=> ({name: x.FirstName}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type of `employees`, then you can do it just as simple as:

```
employees.map((x: Employee)=> {name: x.FirstName});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're assigning the result of `map` to something. If you give that something the type you want, Intellisense should pick it up. Like this:

```js
interface Human {
  name: string;
}

const employees = [{ FirstName: "1" }, { FirstName: "2" }, { FirstName: "3" }];

const humans: Human[] = employees.map(e => ({ name: e.FirstName }));
```

[image]